# a definition for system-wide logging mechanism?

Tags: architecture, software-design

While going through some software architecture documents, I came a cross the following:

Stakeholder: Operations/Testers
The Operations Staff and Testers are concerned with two aspects. Firstly, how the system will be deployed. Secondly, both stakeholders are interested in a system-wide logging mechanism, that is configurable to a degree where they may specify different logging levels and even turning logging on and off for a specific part of the system.

I found this hard to understand, so may someone please simplify it somehow?

Furthermore, what is meant by system-wide and system-wide logging? And how can they be turned off and on?

I tried to google, but everything I found included abstract information that doesn't explain the problem, making it more difficult to understand!

thanks

Comment: For which architecture? For android it's logcat; for unix it's dmesg...

Comment: @Shark Actually I'm supposed to write some documentation for a system that we have designed, and we have decided to use Linux, and a database built using MySQL !

Comment: look into `dmesg` then, perhaps it helps you out.

Comment: @Shark so if the system is deployed over Linux for example, that means it should use Liuns logging methods ?

Comment: nothing is forcing you; you could use a simple ringbuffer or a textfile as well.

Comment: @Shark thanks that was a relief, may you please give a definition for system-wide? :)

Comment: System-wide logging is `logging statements from the whole system (and/as well as it's whole software stack) collected/directed at one output point`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's start with the basics:**

> What is a log statement?

Log statements include information used to record the events that take place in a program during its execution. They are often used to help simplify the debugging process by outputting errors (and other possibly relevant information) that occur within a system. Depending on what types of events/information you decide to log it can potentially help you and your fellow developers, system administrators, testers, etc. I won't get too much into this but too much logging can also prove to be potentially harmful ([see our very own StackOverflow as an example](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-logging/)).

> What is meant by system-wide and system-wide logging?

System-wide logging simply means that your logging capability spans the entirety of your system or application, for example if you have a backend and a frontend then a system-wide logging implementation would include both of them (along with any other components that make up your 'system').

> And how can they be turned off and on?

How the logging can be turned on or off is up to you and the design of your logging mechanism but it can be as simple as a global variable that determines if your system-wide logging features is turned on or off.